# Algolia view match score / confidence level as part of the returned object

Tags: flutter, dart, algolia, firebase-extensions

We are using Algolia to display a list of results based on the users search criteria. We need to know the confidence level of results so that we can filter out results below a certain level.

Ex.
If there are 100 records, we only want to display the records with a confidence level above 90%. This can either be 5 records, or 50 records. It's not determined by the index value / position in the returned list. Its based on the score

Adding the getRankingInfo field returns the following for a query with matches, we limited the results to 5:

```
{"nbTypos":0,"firstMatchedWord":0,"proximityDistance":6,"userScore":4216,"geoDistance":0,"geoPrecision":1,"nbExactWords":4,"words":5,"filters":0}
{"nbTypos":0,"firstMatchedWord":0,"proximityDistance":6,"userScore":4210,"geoDistance":0,"geoPrecision":1,"nbExactWords":4,"words":5,"filters":0}
{"nbTypos":0,"firstMatchedWord":0,"proximityDistance":8,"userScore":7801,"geoDistance":0,"geoPrecision":1,"nbExactWords":4,"words":5,"filters":0}
{"nbTypos":0,"firstMatchedWord":0,"proximityDistance":8,"userScore":4215,"geoDistance":0,"geoPrecision":1,"nbExactWords":4,"words":5,"filters":0}
{"nbTypos":0,"firstMatchedWord":0,"proximityDistance":8,"userScore":4214,"geoDistance":0,"geoPrecision":1,"nbExactWords":4,"words":5,"filters":0}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to use the information below to get to a "confidence" level?

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/getRankingInfo/

Comment: As @cmgchess linked, adding `"getRankingInfo": true` to your search will send all of the scoring info back as part of the search response. Note that Algolia Search results don't use a "confidence level" rather a numeric score based on ranking criteria.  Recommend matches use confidence levels.